# 3D Pyramid chart in d3.js

Tags: svg, charts, d3.js, fusioncharts

Am in need of a 3D pyramid chart (using d3.js) like the one which is present in fusion charts(http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/#pyramid-chart).

My questions are

1. Is it possible to create that chart using d3 library?
2. Is there any alternative open-source library having this feature?
3. If it is possible using d3 library please refer to some site or few coding sets to create a triangle 3D structure.

Comment: A pyramid chart like [this](http://www.jasondavies.com/d3-pyramid/)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff. I have already looked at it but i require like the one described in the link mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Prakash Do u still need 3D Pyramid Chart...

Answer (score -1):

Here is what your are trying to find.
Please do comment if you like it and help you in getting you reach your goal.

http://jsfiddle.net/akashtyagi40/fptv739g/3/

```
var colorArray1 = ["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#d62728", "#9467bd", "#8c564b", "#e377c2", "#7f7f7f", "#bcbd22"];
var data1 = [200, 150, 100, 100, 202, 201, 50];

var labelArray = ["DUSTER", "Qualis", "Scorpio", "Eco Sport", "Honda city", "Altis", "EON"];
var confg1 = {
    "data": data1,
    "colorArray": colorArray1,
    "labels": labelArray,
    "unit": "M$"
};

$(document).ready(function () {

    var stocChart20=$("#draw3DPyramidChartWithoutSlice").stocCharts();
        stocChart20.draw3DPyramidSliceChart(confg1);

});
```

Comment: The link needs an update , has no chart in the result panel